# How can I install drivers and other applications without an Internet connection?

Tags: 12.04, installation, offline

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I install software or packages without Internet (offline)?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/974/how-can-i-install-software-or-packages-without-internet-offline)

I'm Zaw Lin from Myanmar and i'm new to ubuntu. I'm having difficulties about installing drivers and other post installation. Biggest problem is i can't get offline installer for drivers and other application likes antivirus and codecs. Installation and accessing the installed program is confusing. If this is already answered, then i'm sorry. I searched over and over again but i only got the solution that requires internet connection. 
Here is my desktop PC specs

Core i3 550 
1gbx2 (2gb RAM)
nvidia 440 GT
Seagate 160 gb HD

Thank for any advices and help.

Answer (score 0):

There are some answers for offline installation of packages here = [How can I install software or packages without Internet (offline)?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/974/how-can-i-install-software-or-packages-without-internet-offline)

There is a manual for ubuntu here = http://ubuntu-manual.org/